# How to solve string pattern puzzle by using preg_replace function?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am not familiar with preg_replace function of php. I need to solve an issue by using this function.

My string is **sidebarCond/none.php**. I need to remove folder name whatever it is (like: **sidebarCond/** or **folder-name/**) and also the extension (Like: **.php** or **.html**).

```
$sidebar = 'sidebarCond/none.php';
$sidebar = str_replace( 'sidebarCond/', '', $sidebar );
$sidebar = str_replace( '.php', '', $sidebar );
```

This is the code of how I solve my problem, but this is not a smart solution.

Comment: The solution to not being familiar with a function would be a [link to the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Albeit, in this case, [`basename`](http://php.net/basename) likely being the simpler alternative.

Comment: Do you have to use preg_replace? Or preg match if you would only match it?

Comment: I need to the solution if the pattern is like 'sidebarCond/none.php'. @the-fourth-bird

Comment: If the accepted answer works for you, I think that would  be the best approach.

Comment: It's working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use string functions in this case. Use [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$sidebar = 'sidebarCond/none.php';
$sidebar = pathinfo($sidebar)['filename'];
```

OR

```
$sidebar = 'sidebarCond/none.php';
$sidebar = pathinfo($sidebar, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```